# Why is a directive within a Virtual Host considered global?

Tags: configuration, debian

The documentation of the `H2Upgrade` directive in the [httpd documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html) about HTTP/2 says that

> This should be used inside a `<VirtualHost>` section to enable Upgrades to HTTP/2 for that virtual host.

I have two virtual hosts, both listening on plain HTTP only. This is my httpd config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Protocols h2c http/1.1 http/1.0
    H2Upgrade on
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    Protocols h2c http/1.1 http/1.0
    H2Upgrade off
    ServerName test.mydomain.loc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/apps
</VirtualHost>
```

Tests with `curl` show that with varying the host name, the correct virtual host is chosen (it is easy to tell them apart, as they have different document root directories).

```
curl --http2 -vLo- 'http://test.mydomain.loc/test.html'
```

However, only the directive `H2Upgrade` in the first (default) virtual host is used for both virtual hosts. In the second virutal host, the directive is completely useless.

I want `H2Upgrade` to be turned on in the first virtual host, and off in the second one. How to do it?

By the way, turning them around does not work either. Also, this was just a show case, normally these are two separate files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

HTTP/2 with Upgrade starts with a usual HTTP/1.1 header with an additional field requesting for upgrade:

```
GET /test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: test.mydomain.loc
User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
Accept: */*
Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
Upgrade: h2c
```

The server should choose the right virtual host based on this, and then simply ignore the upgrade request (just like it does when `H2Upgrade` is turned off in the first virtual host).

Comment: I do not think it is possible. HTTP2 is a new protocol. How Apache could know which virtualhost to use without starting to communicate? But starting to communicate means to choose protocol. You may make a webserver to handle both, but it would be high inefficient, so contrary to the HTTP2 purposes. [HTTPS uses a different port]

Comment: Please link to the bug report that you filed with Apache. If you haven't filed one, then go do that now.

Answer (score 0):

I see mod_http2 has a [new version that allows more refined scope of H2Upgrade](https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/releases/tag/v1.12.0):

> H2Upgrade can be configured per directory/location. Test case added.

It doesn’t explicitly say this can be defined per VirtualHost but worth trying. It has not be included in an Apache release (will be in 2.4.39 I would guess) so needs to be downloaded and compiled separately to use it. Details of how to do that are in this blog post: https://www.tunetheweb.com/performance/http2/